# Convert session object to type of object passed in

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a generic method in ASP.NET MVC 5 where an Object is passed into a method and a session object name  and it converts the seesion object to the type of the object that was passed in. Something like

```
   public static object GetSessionItem(object target, string sessionName)
   {
        var type = target.GetType();
        var sessionObject = ( type  )currentSession[sessionName];
        return sessionObject;
   }
```

Where I could then call it like

```
   UserData data = (UserData)GetSessionItem(new UserData(),"UserSessionName")
```

I think this can be done using reflection but am exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/559508/Session-Management-With-Generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generics

```
public static T GetSessionItem<T>(string sessionName)
{
    T sessionObject = currentSession[sessionName] as T;
    return sessionObject;
}
```

Call it like

```
UserData data = GetSessionItem<UserData>("UserSessionName")
```

Comment: That worked although to note I had to do the following (T)currentSession[sessionName] over currentSession[sessionName] as T